# Pre-run / Pre-actions in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, abap

in Eclipse I am seaching for an option to specify user-defined pre-run actions which will be executed each time I try to execute an application.

For example: In some programming languages it might be necessary to (1) save (2) compile (3) activate etc. the source code before you can execute it. Each step itself is necessary and meaningful, no doubt. But each step is an single action in its own.

I would like to have kind of a shortcut to run these actions in an user-defined order before the execution starts.

I know the feature of running external tools in Eclipse. That's not what I am looking for!

Greets!

Comment: Use a _Launch Group_ to run multiple launch configurations in sequence or in parallel. Use an [Ant](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) or [Non-Ant](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-96_non_ant_pjs.htm) project builder for things that are better done on save.